# Are the scriptures aware of the existence of other religions in Kali Yuga?

Tags: scripture, other-religions, kali-yuga

Hindu Dharma or the Sanatan Dharma claims Universe is cyclic. Currently we are living in Kali yuga. Scriptures predict arrival of Kalki Avatar. However, I guess, scriptures do not mention existence of Christians, Muslims or Buddhists.
My question is: do scriptures mention existence of other social groups like Muslim, Christians etc in Kali Yuga?

Comment: Yes Scriptures know about Buddhism and Jainism. I did not come across Islam or Christianity. In Bhavishya Puraana there are stories such as some king killed all mlechhas ,so head mlechha worshiped Vishnu and He blessed Mlecchas that I will come to bless you.which seems to be Jesus story. But as we all know Bhavishya Puraana is profusely interpolated, so we cannot vouch for credibility of this story

Comment: @AnuragSingh ok. Can you quote a scripture where Buddha is mentioned ?

Comment: दुष्टयज्ञविघाताय पशुहिंसानिवृत्तये ॥ १३ ॥ 
बौद्धरूपं दधौ योऽसौ तस्मै देवाय ते नमः । - "Obeisances to Thee O Vishnu , who took form of Buddha for eradicating Yagyas done by wrong people, and eho removed the practice of Pashu Hinsaa (Pashu Bali et cetera)" Devi Puraana, 10 Skandha , Chapter 5. Also, Buddhists and Jains were completely opposed in Scriptures as far as I saw, maybe because Buddhist don't do Murti Pooja, don't believe in Para Brahma, don't do Yagya et cetera.

Answer (score 3):

The Atharva Veda itself is having the following Mantra which accepts the existence of various religions on earth. But it does not name any specific religion.

> Janam Vibhrati VahudhA VichAsam - 1
>   **NAnAdhArmAn Prithvi** - 2
>  YathA Okasam - 3
>  Sahasram DhArA Dravinasya Me DuhAm - 4
>  Dhruveva Dhenuh Anapasphuranthi - 5
>
> **Earth has people who speak various tongues - 1, and those who have various religions** - **2, according to their places of abode - 3,**
>   (May She or the Earth) pour for me treasures in a thousand streams - 4, like a constant cow that never fails - 5.
>
> **Atharva Veda KAnda 12, Sukta 1, Mantra 45.**

And, apart from that, the Bhavisya Purana too mentions about the propounders of religions like Islam, Christianity.

From an introductory note of the Purana as found on [this page](http://www.astrojyoti.com/bhavishyapurana.htm):

> The Bhavishya Purana is the eleventh among the Puranas and it contains
>   five parts. The first part contains a description of the genesis,
>   greatness of the deities and worship of Lord Vishnu, Shiva and Surya.
>   Second, third and fourth parts describe about the greatness of Shiva,
>   Vishnu and Surya respectively.
>
> **It gives very accurate forecasts about Jesus Christ, Mohammad, Adam and Eve, Noah’s Ark,** the fall of Sanskrit and coming of other
>   languages, about **the coming of Buddha**, Madhavacharya,
>   Chandragupta, Ashoka, Jayadeva and Krishna Chaitanya and about
>   Kutubuddin & the Shaws ruling Delhi. The relevant translations of
>   above events are given on this section.

In particular, the verses in which Jesus Christ is predicted are as follows:

> “Ruling over the Aryans was a king called Salivahana, the grandson of
>   Vikramaditya, who occupied the throne of his father. He defeated the
>   Shakas who were very difficult to subdue, the Cinas, the people from
>   Tittiri and Bahikaus who could assume any form at will. He also
>   defeated the people from Rome and the descendants of Khuru, who were
>   deceitful and wicked. He punished them severely and took their wealth.
>   Salivahana thus established the boundaries dividing the separate
>   countries of the Mlecchas and the Aryans. In this way Sindusthan came
>   to be known as the greatest country. That personality appointed the
>   abode of the Mlecchas beyond the Sindhu River and to the west.”
>   (verses 17-21)
>
> ekadaa tu shakadhisho
>  himatungari samaayayau
>  hunadeshasya
>   madhye vai
>  giristhan purusam shubhano
>  dadarsha balaram raajaa
>
> Once upon a time the subduer of the Sakas went towards Himatunga and
>   in the middle of the Huna country (Hunadesh – the area near Manasa
>   Sarovara or Kailash mountain in Western Tibet), the powerful king saw
>   an auspicious man who was living on a mountain. The man’s complexion
>   was golden and his clothes were white (22).
>
> ko bharam iti tam praaha
>  su hovacha mudanvitah
>  iishaa purtagm
>   maam viddhi
>  kumaarigarbha sambhavam
>
> “The king asked, ‘Who are you sir?’ ‘You should know that I am Isha
>   Putra, the Son of God’. he replied blissfully, and ‘am born of a
>   virgin.’ (23)”
>
> mleccha dharmasya vaktaram
>  satyavata paraayanam
>  iti srutva
>   nrpa praaha
>  dharmah ko bhavato matah
>
> ” ‘I am the expounder of the religion of the Mlecchas and I strictly
>   adhere to the Absolute Truth.’ Hearing this the king enquired, ‘What
>   are religious principles according to you opinion?’ (24)
>
> shruto vaaca mahaaraaja
>  praapte satyasya samkshaye
>   nirmaaryaade mlechadeshe
>  masiiho ‘ham samagatah
>
> iishaamasii ca dasyuunaa
>  praadurbhuutaa bhayankarii
>  taamaham
>   mlecchataah praapya
>  masiihatva mupaagatah
>
> “Hearing this questions of Salivahara, Isha putra said, ‘O king, when
>   the destruction of the truth occurred, I, Masiha the prophet, came to
>   this country of degraded people where there are no rules and
>   regulations. Finding that fearful irreligious condition of the
>   barbarians spreading from Mleccha-Desha, I have taken to
>   prophethood’.” (25,26)

These verses are from Bhavishya Purana, Pratisarga Parva, Chaturyuga Khanda Dvitiyadhyayah, 19th Chapter.

Here, Jesus Christ is mentioned as "Isha Putra" and at another place as "Masiah".

Also note that some people believe certain portions (specially the ones which predict the prophets of some other religions) of this Purana to be interpolated (later added). But that's probably because those people can not accept the fact that the Hindu Rishis were being able to predict the future with such degree of accuracy.

Furthermore, discussion can not be based on such claims, because interpolation claims can only be made. Such claims can not be proven or refuted with any degree of conviction.

Comment: relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3ABhavishya_Purana

Comment: Claims of Interpolation are made based on the fact that various manuscripts of the purana are inconsistent. It's basic clue chasing from here. Why should any person accept your Speculations on the supposed behaviour of Hindu Rishis? Furthermore, any discussion that claims these are not valid arguments can only be made. Such claims can not be proven or refuted with any degree of conviction.